# CSS navigation bar - centering based on element within nav bar

Tags: css, navbar

I'm trying to create a nav bar with four elements, two smaller buttons that will link to the homepage and a contact page, and then two larger buttons that will link to the two main sections of the site. I'm trying to position things in such a way that the two large buttons are centered, with the two smaller buttons to the left of them.

I can't "margin: 0 auto;" the two large buttons inside their own div as I would have to set it to "display: block;" which sets them on a different line than the smaller buttons, and absolutely positioning things messes up the layout as soon as the browser window changes.

I feel like I'm missing something simple here. Am I going at this from the wrong angle?

Here's a Dabblet of what I have at the moment... http://dabblet.com/gist/6287837

HTML

```
<div id="nav-container">
<div id="small-button-container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/47x22" class="small-button01" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/70x42" class="small-button02" />
</div>
<div id="big-button-container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/360x64" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/360x64" />
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#nav-container{
outline: 1px red dashed;
width: 1000px;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;}

#small-button-container{
display: inline-block;
width: 136px;
position: relative;
top: -22px;
left: 40px;}

#big-button-container{
display: inline-block;
width: 780px;
height: 64px;
margin-left: 70px;}

.small-button01{
display: inline;
position: relative;
left: 5px;}

.small-button02{
display: inline;
position: relative;
left: 15px;}
```

Comment: Here you go. http://dabblet.com/gist/6288178 . Notice there's not enough space for the small buttons that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `position: absolute;` to your `#small-button-container`, so the the big buttons will centre.

Note we put `position: relative;` on the parent container so the `#small-button-container` will be positioned absolutely relative to it's parent.

**CSS**

```css
#nav-container {
    outline: 1px red dashed;
    width: 1000px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
#small-button-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

**[Demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/6288198)**

Answer (score 0):

In addition to position: absolute you can also try using a negative left margin on #nav-container if you know the computed width of #small-button-container. You can use text-align: center on #nav-container. Since it's a div you don't need to use display:block too. If you have additional padding on #small-button-container you'll need to take this into account.

```
#nav-container {
   margin: 0px auto;
   text-align: center;
   margin-left: -136px;
}
```